# Highcharts динамический стиль для yaxis categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) 
    {
        tasks.push({
                name: test[i].Name,
                color: test[i].Color,
                intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.parse(test[i].DateFrom),
                to: Date.parse(test[i].DateTo),
                label: test[i].Name
                }]});
                names.push(test[i].Name);
    }


        var series = [];
        $.each(tasks, function(i, task) {
            var item = {
                name: task.name,
                color:task.color,
                data: []
            };
            $.each(task.intervals, function(j, interval) {
                item.data.push({
                    x: interval.from,
                    y: i,
                    label: interval.label,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to
                }, {
                    x: interval.to,
                    y: i,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to,
                });


                if (task.intervals[j + 1]) {
                    item.data.push(
                        [(interval.to + task.intervals[j + 1].from) / 2, null]
                    );
                }

            });

            series.push(item);
        });

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'big_panel',
                backgroundColor:"black"

            },
                   credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            tooltip: {

                enabled: false

            },

            title: {
                 style: { "color": "#f8c517",
                         fontSize:'20px',
                        "fontFamily": 'a_LCDNova'},
                text: 'Мероприятия'
            },

            xAxis: {
                opposite:true,
                type: 'datetime',
                lineColor: '#f8c517',
                tickColor: '#f8c517',
                labels: {
                    autoRotation: true,
                    style: {
                        whiteSpace: 'normal',
                        fontFamily: 'a_LCDNova',
                        fontSize: "1em",
                        padding: "5px",
                        color: '#f8c517'
                    }
                }

            },

            yAxis: {
                /*categories:names,-------------------------------------------*/
                tickInterval: 1,            
                tickPixelInterval: 200,
                gridLineColor:"#f8c517",
                lineColor: "#f8c517",
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color:  "#f8c517",
                        fontSize: '25px',
                        fontFamily: 'a_LCDNova',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    style: { "color": "#f8c517",
                        "fontFamily": 'a_LCDNova'},
                    text: 'Категории'
                },
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                   fontSize:'15px',
                color: '#f8c517'

            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ tasks[this.y].name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.from)  +
                        ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.to); 
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    lineWidth: 13,

                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'left',
                        color: '#f8c517',
                        formatter: function() {
                         return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: series
        }); 
            chart.yAxis[0].setCategories(names, true, true);
```

есть такой код, я в yaxis жестко прописываю стили. (labels:style:color) мне нужно  для каждый категории поставить свои цвет и стиль. помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: или простой пример    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginBottom: 80
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize:'15px'
                }
            }
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});

Comment: как мне стайл для каждой категории индивидуальный передавать

Comment: Все вопросы, дополнения к вопросу и всё что связанно с вопросом - должно быть в вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Comment: Сорри. Торопился

Comment: Нажмите `править` под вопросом и внесите все изменения, которые необходимы